# PropertyInfo is coming as nothing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code snippet in vb.net . The propertyinfo p is coming out as nothing even though my column name of dataTable is matching with class name attributes

```
Public Class ReflectionMethods(Of T As New)

' function that set the given object from the given data row
  Public Shared Sub SetItemFromRow(item As T, row As DataRow)


    ' go through each column
    For Each c As DataColumn In row.Table.Columns

        ' find the property for the column. at this point i am getting p as nothing
        Dim p As PropertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName)

        ' if exists, set the value
        If p IsNot Nothing AndAlso row(c) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            p.SetValue(item, row(c), Nothing)
        End If
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Final end result that I am getting is a class object with everything set to nothing as it is not passing the if condition.

Hi Jon, I have pasted my class snippet down

```
Public Class StockProduct
Public SupplierName As String
Public ModelName As String
Public ModelDescription As String
Public ProductCategoryName As String
Public ManufacturerName As String
End Class
```

and I have a dataTable with column match 
[image: dataTable where attributes match with the column names] .                         Please note the productcategoryName is matched but not seen in screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class doesn't have any properties. The line

```
Public SupplierName As String
```

creates a field, not a property.

To fix your code do one of the following...
either change the class declaration to say

```
Public Property SupplierName As String
```

etc...

or change your property reading code to say

```
Dim p As FieldInfo = item.GetType().GetField(c.ColumnName)
```

Comment: oops yes. you are right, Thanks Roger and Jon . Both were right

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. ColumnName is wrong - doesn't exactly match the name of the property.
2. There is no public property with the name you're expecting. Maybe its a Field or a Private property.

Maybe update your question with an example of the ColumnName from the DataTable, and also the definition of a class that you're attempting to populate.